# How to proceed with this math question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This may seem elementary but I can't seem to find the right steps to take.

$$
3^a =21^b ~~~\mbox{and}~~~~ 7^c = 21^b
$$

Prove that

$$
b= \frac{ac}{a+c}
$$

Comment: $$\large \begin{align}
3^B &= 21^A\\
7^B &= 21^C\\
\Rightarrow\, 21^B &= 21^{A+C}\ \ \ \rm by\ product\ of\ above\\ 
\Rightarrow\ \ \ \  B &= A+C\\[.5em] 
\text{OP is case }\ A,B,C &=  \small \frac{1}a,\, \frac{1}b,\, \frac{1}c \end{align}\qquad\qquad $$

Comment: @BillDubuque Really, a `\large \begin{align}` in a *comment*?

Comment: It does, but it should be an answer IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equations are equivalent to $3=21^{\tfrac{b}{a}}$ and $7=21^{\tfrac{b}{c}}$. From this follows
$$
21^1 = 3\times 7 = 21^{\tfrac{b}{a}+\tfrac{b}{c}}
$$
and thus $1 = \tfrac{b}{a}+\tfrac{b}{c}$ and then the desired relation is easily calculated.

Comment: Assuming $a$ and $c$ do not equal $0$ (which was an issue in the original question)... [+1, btw]

Comment: @peterag you got me there :) Thank you for this remark.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you want to show is equivalent to $b(a+c)=ac$, which we obtain from
\begin{align*}
21^{ac} &= (3\cdot 7)^{ac} = (3^a)^c(7^c)^a = (21^b)^c (21^b)^a = 21^{bc+ba} = 21^{b(a+c)}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$3^a=21^b\implies 3^a=3^b .7^b\implies 3^{a-b}=7^b$ . . . .$(1)$

$7^c=21^b\implies 7^c=3^b.7^b\implies 7^{(c-b)}=3^b$ . . . . $(2)$

Taking logarithm both side of $(1)$ & $(2)$,

$(a-b)\log 3=b \log 7\implies\frac{\log 3}{\log 7}=\frac{b}{a-b}$

$(c-b)\log 7=b \log 3\implies\frac{\log 3}{\log 7}=\frac{c-b}{b}$

which gives $\frac{b}{a-b}=\frac{c-b}{b}\implies b^2=ac-b(a+c)+b^2\implies b= \frac{ac}{a+c}$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the logarithm leads (alsmost) directly to the result (exculding $a=c= 0$):

\begin{eqnarray*}
a\log 3 & = & b\log 21 & = & b(\log 3 + \log 7) \\
c\log 7 & = & b\log 21 & = & b(\log 3 + \log 7)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows
$$\frac{a}{c} = \frac{\log 7}{\log 3}$$ 
Hence,
$$b = a\frac{\log 3}{\log 3 + \log 7}= a\frac{1}{1 + \frac{\log 7}{\log 3}}= a\frac{1}{1 + \frac{a}{c}}=\frac{ac}{c+a}$$
$$$$